# Preventing SESSION to expire during a registration form

Tags: php, session

I have a multi step registration form. In each step I store all the data in the $_SESSION array. I want to prevent that the $_SESSION gets deleted after a certain time.

Originally, I thought that the $_SESSION array only gets deleted if the browser is closed. I did not know that it also gets deleted after a certain amount of time.

How can I avoid my $_SESSION array to be deleted during the registration form?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_save_path('/path/to/writable/directory/inside/your/account');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3*60*60); // 3 hours
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', FALSE);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', TRUE);
session_start();
?>
```

Comment: This only sets the lifetime up to 3 hours right? So its still possible that by some interruption from the real world the users session might expire?

Comment: u can use logout destroy seesion

Comment: I want actually to prevent the session from being destroyed aslong as the browser is not closed.

Comment: session_start();
$now = time();
if (isset($_SESSION['discard_after']) && $now > $_SESSION['discard_after']) {
    // this session has worn out its welcome; kill it and start a brand new one
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
}
$_SESSION['discard_after'] = $now + 3600;

Comment: sorry but your codes deletes the session and frees the variables after a certain time. I want the opposite.

Comment: much confused what u exactly wnat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59851/discussion-between-saurav-and-adam).